# JPA persistence with nested XML data does not work

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I want to persist the following XML. I just want to persist the tosaveElements but i need the date Property also in my toSave Elements.

```
<data date="01/Jul/2016">
    <tosave>
        <a>a1</a>
        <b>b1</b>
        <c>c1</c>
        <d>d1</d>
        <e>e1</e>
    </tosave>
    <tosave>
        <a>a2</a>
        <b>b2</b>
        <c>c2</c>
        <d>d2</d>
        <e>e2</e>
    </tosave>
</data>
```

I have the following XML, and the Marshalling seams to work correctly

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">
    <stream name="Upload" xmlType="none" format="xml">
        <record name="data" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" class="Wrapperclass">
            <field name="date" xmlName="date" xmlType="attribute" />
            <segment name="items" xmlName="tosave" collection="list" class="TosaveClass" minOccurs="1"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <field name="a" xmlName="a"/>
                <field name="b" xmlName="b"/>
                <property name="h" value="1"/>
                <property name="i" value="GB"/> 
            </segment>
         </record>
    </stream>
</beanio>
```

The tosaveClass is a Class with an already working annotation (the class is already in use). 
The Problem seams to be the Wrapperclass because JPA tries to persist it.
And i get the following Error Message

```
No metadata was found for type "Wrapperclass". The class is not enhanced.
FailedObject: Wrapperclass
```

As this class is just a simple wrapper class i do not want to persist this class.

```
public class wrapperclass {

    private List<Tosave> items;
    private String date;

    public List<Tosave> getCurrencyItems() {
        return items;
    }
    public void setTosaveItems(List<Tosave> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<v> postProcessBeanIO(String doPostProcessing)
            throws BeanIOException {
        List<Tosave> items = new ArrayList<Tosave>();

        //do some datemodification

        for (Tosave item : items) {

            // Remove duplicates
            if (!IsCurrencyCodeInList(items, item.getCode())) {
                // Set date
                item.setValidFrom(date);
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

//Getter&Setter
}
```

The Tosave class is included in the persistance.xml 
Is there an annotation that makes it possible that jpa does not try to persist the wrapper class ?

Comment: JPA does not use "XML". It uses Entity classes. Post your classes and persistence code.

Comment: That was already clear, because of that i posted the bean io.. The Jpa Anotation of the ToSave Class is already working in multiple other cases and as it is a very simple class its not relavant for the example.

Comment: If you want to DEBUG your question then you post the entities, and the persistence code ... not the input to some conversion process that then becomes the objects to be persisted. If you don't, then good luck.